# Why does my modal close before I am able to fill it out?

Tags: javascript, forms, async-await

I have a form that when the submit button is clicked it first runs through validation making sure all the required fields are filled out then it calls the google validate address api and if the address isn't valid a popup modal should appear and prevent the form from submitting until the address is valid.  The issue I am facing is if I enter an invalid address the modal is only displaying for a split second and then submitting my form without filling out the modal.  The form is being created with razor and my onsubmit is calling a validateForm function.  This looks like so,

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(action, "appointments", routeValues, FormMethod.Post, new RouteValueDictionary(new { @id = "myForm", @name = "myForm", @class = "form-horizontal", onsubmit = "return formHelper.validateForm(this);" })))
```

Inside the validateForm function, I am calling a validateAddress function like so,

```
  validateForm: function (t) {
    validateAddress().then(() => {
        if (addressConfirmed.value != 'true') {
            console.log('Line 641 addressConfirmed is still false');
            return false;
        }
        else {
            console.log('Line 645 addressConfirmed is true');
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Originally, I was calling this function like this

```
validateForm: function (t) {
  validateAddress();
  return false;
}
```

which was working to display the modal when the address was invalid without submitting the form until a selection was made on the modal.  The issue with calling it this way is that it is preventing the form from being submitted when the address has no validation issues to begin with.  The page would stay on the form without the form getting submitted and then when the submit button was clicked a second time then the form would submit.  I need a way to submit the form if there are no address validation issues and if there are display the modal until the user selects an option.  Since the validateAddress function is async I thought if I added a .then to the function call it would first call validateAddress, get a response and then return false if the address has not been confirmed and the return false would cause the form to not submit.

This is my validateAddress function:

```
async function validateAddress() {
    const response = await fetch('https://addressvalidation.googleapis.com/v1:validateAddress?key=@googleApiKey', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            "address": {
                "regionCode": "US",
                "addressLines": [
                    patientAddressLine.value
                ],
                "locality": patientCity.value,
                "administrativeArea": patientStateCode.value,
                "postalCode": patientPostalCode.value
            },
            "enableUspsCass": true
        })
    });
    if (!response.ok) {
       console.log(response.status);
    } else {
       const data = await response.json();
        console.log(data);
        const responseAddress = data.result.address;
        const responseVerdict = data.result.verdict;
        const googleAddressLine = responseAddress.postalAddress.addressLines[0];
        const googleCity = responseAddress.postalAddress.locality;
        const googleState = responseAddress.postalAddress.administrativeArea;
        const googleZipcode = responseAddress.postalAddress.postalCode;
        const hasInferredComponents = responseVerdict.hasInferredComponents;
        const addressComplete = responseVerdict.addressComplete;
        const hasReplacedComponents = responseVerdict.hasReplacedComponents;
        const hasUnconfirmedComponents = responseVerdict.hasUnconfirmedComponents;
        const missingComponentTypes = responseAddress.missingComponentTypes;
        // need if statement to only do this if the address is invalid
        // if hasInferredComponents is true or addressComplete is false and no validation errors then create the modal.  If it is false then submit the form
        if (hasInferredComponents || !addressComplete || hasReplacedComponents || missingComponentTypes) {
            console.log('inside if statement on line 919');
            populateModalValues(googleAddressLine, googleCity, googleState, googleZipcode, missingComponentTypes, hasInferredComponents, hasReplacedComponents);
            console.log('modal values should be populated');
            recommendedChangesModal.showModal();
            console.log('modal should show');
        } else if (hasUnconfirmedComponents) {
            console.log('address could not be verified');
            populateModalValidationIssues(responseAddress.unconfirmedComponentTypes);
            addressVerificationModal.showModal();
        } else {
            addressConfirmed.value = 'true';
            console.log('address confirmed is true');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: the way you've written `validateForm`, it is a function that immediately returns `undefined` - and clearly, `validateAddress` is asynchronous, so, nothing executed in there will have any influence on running `validateForm`

Comment: I don't understand.  How does it immediately return undefined?  validateForm is called when on submit happens.  Where would I call validateAddress if not within validateForm?

Comment: it calls `validateAddress`, disregards the Promise that returns asynchronously, and that's it, so, no return same as return undefined

Comment: How do I get it to not disregard the promise?  If I do it like this, validateForm: function (t) {
  validateAddress();
  return false;
} The modal stays open until it is filled out, but this prevents the form from submitting if there are no address validation issues.

Comment: you write code that doesn't

Answer (score -1):

Let the browser work for you by invoking the powerful built-in **client-side form validation**, and you can always add custom prerequisites as well if desired.

Study the tutorial here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Form_validation

Typical example...

```
<input id="choose" name="i-like" required />
```